# Node.js app cluster load balancing using PM2 on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, pm2

**Node.js version**: 4.5.0 - **PM2 version**: 2.0.18

I have an in-house Node.js app under test. I'm using pm2 for clustering and I assumed it will take care of load balancing. **BUT** when I ran my app on Windows and looking at the processes (using pm2 monit command) I cannot see even distribution of load. Sometimes one process spike to 70% and the other are not doing anything.

So, I think the load balancer of pm2 mechanism is at fault. I read somewhere that Its not using round robin on windows machines?

Could someone share their experience about this issue.

Also, I thought maybe Nginx is another solution to configure it as a load balancer in front of the pm2 Node.js cluster but not quite sure about the configuration

Comment: Have you tried implementing the nodejs clusters from your app with a method similar to: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-a-node-js-cluster-for-speeding-up-your-apps/ ?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, I'm aware of the method discussed in the article. But, it is clearly mentioned that round-robin approached in not working on windows.